# R Count Frequency Of Group In Row

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data =data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,7,7,7,7),
score=c(10,6,1,7,6,0,8,5,5,1),
WANT=c(3,3,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,4))
```

I hope to count the number of rows for each id and make new variable WANT that equals to the number of rows the id appears. My attempts

```
library(dplyr)    
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(WANT = tally(id)))
```

Evaluation error: argument "x" is missing, with no default.

Comment: You may need `data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
   tally  %>% right_join(data)` or `data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(n = n())`

Comment: FYI, you can do just `data %>% add_count(id)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `add_count`

```
data %>% group_by(id) %>% add_count()
```